# How to get Doxygen to produce Call graphs for OpenVSource Code?PN

Tags: c, doxygen, openvpn

I have installed and configured doxygen for openvpn source code, but I am unable to get the call graphs and diagrams of it. I only get config-msvc.h    and config.h files in the file list of code documentation. 
Can anybody tell me how to configure doxygen to produces these call and caller trees for openvpn source code ? I do have graphviz installed.

Comment: In the doxyfile you'll find the tag `RECURSIVE`. Set this one to `YES` to tell doxygen that it shall search subdirectories for input files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your doxygen file (ex- project_name.doxygen).
- In that you will see one option like **Diagrams to Generate**.
- In that select all check boxes under last option named **Use Dot tool from the graphViz package to generate**.
- And if there are many directoris in your project you need to add that directory path in Input Directories.
- I am attaching image, hope this will help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

download (if not present in your installation) doxhygen config file usually name doxyfile. it is self explanatory. set input path for your project and suitable output files. set limit on call graphs. its very simple. just run doxygen in the directory where your doxyfile is present. doxygen first looks in the current directory for doxyfile so it will run your doxyfile.

if still after setting all above paramets, you are not able to have call graphs, check the path of your dot tool and give that path in *dot_path* switch
also check if you are using older than IE9, dont use svg format for graph.

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. I figured it out :)